# php mysql query fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have this php code to fill a table with some data come to an mysl db,
but when i exec it said

```
"Fatal error: Call to undefined method MysqlClass::query()"


<?php 
include "config.php"; 
$data = new Mysqlclass();
$data->connetti(); 
$post_sql = $data->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($post_sql) > 0) 
    {while($post_obj = $Data->estrai($post_sql))
        {$id=$post_obj->id; 
            $name = stripcslashes($post_obj->name); 
            $cat = stripcslashes($post_obj->category);
            $price= stripcslashes($post_obj->price);
            echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$name."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$cat."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$price."</td>";
        }
    }else{
        echo"Tabella vuota";
    }
    $data->disconnetti();
?>
```

The error is in 2 line when i declare the `$Data->query`.

maybe the function query is not correct, i'm new to php scripting.

I've taken this code in a tutorial. i don't know if the "query" and "estrai" (extract) key is correct.

Here is the config file:

```
<?php

    class MysqlClass
    {
      private $nomehost = "localhost";     
      private $nomeuser = "root";          
      private $password = "xxxxx"; 
      private $nomedb = "intse";
      private $attiva = false;
      public function connetti()
      {
        if(!$this->attiva)
        {
          if($connessione = mysql_connect($this->nomehost,$this->nomeuser,$this->password) or die (mysql_error()))
          {
            $selezione = mysql_select_db($this->nomedb,$connessione) or die (mysql_error());
          }
        } else{
          return true;
        }
      } 
      public function disconnetti()
      {
        if($this->attiva)
        {
          if(mysql_close())
          {
            $this->attiva = false; 
            return true; 
          } else {
             return false; 
          }
        }
      }
    }  
    ?>
```

http://imageshack.com/a/img35/1966/pd0v.png
So now i must to fill row2 with db 2nd entry and row3 with db 3rd entry, and increase number of table row in html to fill other db entries.
thanks.

Comment: Your connection to the db failed. You need to figure out why.

Comment: No idea without seeing the class file

Comment: thanks i will check the config, maybe mysql doesn't accept my connection

Comment: Yep, this seems that the `Mysqlclass` does not have the method `query` available in it. Is the correct class being called or are you using the correct method to run the query? It's hard to tell without seeing the code for `Mysqlclass`.

Comment: If you are taking this code from a tutorial, are you sure you have edited `config.php` to suit your database? Assuming that `config.php` will contain the database credentials.

Comment: i've updated the answer including config.php file. thanks

Comment: erm, would you be kind enough to use either `$data` or `$Data` uniformly? (I think that is causing the error as well)

Comment: sorry but i'm not really good in php scripting, i must to change $Data in $data? or i must to change $Data in $somethingelse to avoid conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are case sensitive, ($Data->estrai);
Using $data->query will use the query method from your MysqlClass class, not the system predefined one, you you need to write one for it. 
If you want to use the method from your class like $data->method(), you need to build it in your class. For example

```
public function query($sql) {

    return mysql_query($sql);

}
```

Also I can't see the usage of $this->attiva since you didn't set it to TRUE somewhere.
$selezione is also useless.

**UPDATES:**

mysql_select_db only returns a boolean value, you don't need it other than reporting a fail select (die). 
It should be something like this (if I didn't make any syntax mistake..):

```
<?php 

include 'config.php'; 

$data = new MysqlClass();
$data->connetti();

$post_sql = $data->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC"); 

if(mysql_num_rows($post_sql) > 0) {

    while($post_obj = $data->estrai($post_sql)) {

        // the data it returns is an array, not object
        // so it should be $post_obj['key'] not $post_obj->key

        $id = $post_obj['id'];
        $name = stripcslashes($post_obj['name']);
        $cat = stripcslashes($post_obj['category']);
        $price = stripcslashes($post_obj['price']);

        echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$name."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$cat."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$price."</td>";
    }

} else {

    echo 'Tabella vuota';

}

$data->disconnetti();

?>
```

.

```
<?php

class MysqlClass {

    private $nomehost = 'localhost';     
    private $nomeuser = 'root';          
    private $password = 'xxxxx'; 
    private $nomedb = 'intse';
    private $attiva = FALSE;
    private $connessione;

    public function connetti() {

        if(!$this->attiva && ($this->connessione = mysql_connect($this->nomehost, $this->nomeuser, $this->password) or die(mysql_error()))) {

            mysql_select_db($this->nomedb, $this->connessione) or die(mysql_error());
            $this->attiva = TRUE; // Now this becomes useful, because the value has been set

        }

        return $this->attiva;

    } 

    // Method to build up the query

    public function query($sql) {

        return mysql_query($sql, $this->connessione);

    }

    // Method to extract information from the query

    public function estrai($query) {

        return mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    }

    public function disconnetti() {

        // More straight forward way to return the status

        if($this->attiva) return mysql_close($this->connessione);

        return FALSE;

    }

}
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
<?php 

include 'config.php'; 

$data = new MysqlClass();
$data->connetti();

$post_sql = $data->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC"); 

echo '<table>';

if(mysql_num_rows($post_sql) > 0) {

    while($post_obj = $data->estrai($post_sql)) {

        // the data it returns is an array, not object
        // so it should be $post_obj['key'] not $post_obj->key

        $id = $post_obj['id'];
        $name = stripcslashes($post_obj['name']);
        $cat = stripcslashes($post_obj['category']);
        $price = stripcslashes($post_obj['price']);

        echo '<tr>';

        echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$name."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$cat."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$price."</td>";

        echo '</tr>';

    }

} else {

    echo 'Tabella vuota';

}

echo '</table>';

$data->disconnetti();

?>
```

Comment: sorry but i'm little noob to php, if possible, can you make the modification and repost the file? $selezione (select) make the choise of dbname, isn't correct?

Comment: Thank you a lot, now i've the table completelly filled, now the real question is: i have many row in the page, and many row in the db, i must to fill all the table and add new row in order to fill all the products in page, how i can add new row? if i copy this code in new table row it fill it whit the first record. there is a method to add the second, third ecc.. row?

Comment: @andreyo I don't really get your question, do you mean to insert a row to DB or just add a new blank record in HTML page to fill? If DB, use SQL sentence [INSERT INTO tbl (col, col2, ...) VALUES (data, data2, ...), (...)], if HTML, use Javascript to do it.

Comment: I apologize for my english, suppose you have a table 4x4, (then with the code already written I filled the first row), since I have several rows in the db, how can I fill the remaining rows of the table which it do not overlapping and then write the same record in multiple rows instead of multiple rows from several different records in the same table. 
I hope I have expressed myself well

Comment: @andreyo sorry ur questions seems too complicated (im not a background english speaker..). can u please provide a visual output example?(edit in ur first post)

Comment: @andreyo I saw your visual example, thanks! However I still have some questions, what do you mean by 'fill correct', and do you just need to display all the records from the database in that page? Anyway I've made changes in my post, hope that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks, so... the first is the working row, we've just added with the code you provide, i need to display all the record from the database and in future make more than one page listed. just a list of items and relative info ( such as id, category, price ) taken from a db

Comment: @andreyo that's exactly what your code from above do.. while($post_obj = $data->estrai($post_sql)) extract all the rows you want from the db..

Comment: yes but if i add more row to the db then in html display the same row in horizontal instead of displaying vertically like a normal table.
How i can make the html formatting them vertically? i must to declare row1, row2 etc. to fill in html table? or leave the written code and php automatically makes the row?

Comment: @andreyo Oh I know what do you mean now, u want to display it row by row instead of squeeze them in one row. All you need is a <tr> tag, that's what I've post in my UPDATE2.

Comment: Thank You a Lot, the finale result is like i want it.
thanks to the code you provide i can make all the pages on my first cms. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the specific line you have an error:

```
$post_sql = $data->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Change to this:

```
$post_sql = $Data->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC");
```

The variable **$Data** needs to be Uppercase all time (because you created it like that), PHP is a Case sensitive language.

Hope it helps.